# Power BI - Add slicer for thousands and millions

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

Does anyone know how you can add a power BI slicer so that the values in a matrix go from thousands to millions based on the selection of another slicer?

So if I select all business units then the sum of all values are returned in millions, else if i select one business unit, all values are returned in thousands?

Sorry, I have no DAX code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered nicely here:

https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/

(The DAX below is copied from that page.)

---

1. Create a new parameter table to use in a slicer.

```
Scale =
DATATABLE (
    "Scale", STRING,
    "Denominator", INTEGER,
    {
        { "Units", 1 },
        { "Thousands", 1000 },
        { "Millions", 1000000 }
    }
)
```

2. Incorporate the denominator into your measure(s). For example,

```
Sales Amount :=
VAR RealValue =
    SUMX ( Sales, Sales[Quantity] * Sales[Net Price] )
VAR Denominator =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Scale[Denominator], 1 )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE ( RealValue, Denominator )
RETURN
    Result
```